# Finding duplicates with multiple criteria in Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a list of data that has columns for different users, paths as well as request timestamps, in Excel.

Now the challenge is: A request is counted as duplicate when it's created by the same user, for the same path, within 20 minutes of another request.

I have tried the following code: `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$8,$A2,$B$2:$B$8,$B2)>1, "Duplicate row", "")`

Whereby: Column A is for users, Column B is for paths, in order to find those duplicate entries for same users, same paths.

Then I'm stuck with the time factors. What to do next, guys? How to arrive at the final duplicate requests?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SUMPRODUCT function, if data not sorted:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2=$A$2:$A$13)*(B2=$B$2:$B$13)*(C2-1/24/3<$C$2:$C$13)*(C2+1/24/3>$C$2:$C$13))>1
```

it marks all duplicate rows as `TRUE`

or, if data is sorted by `Time` field ascending:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2=$A$1:A1)*(B2=$B$1:B1)*(C2-1/24/3<$C$1:C1))>0
```

it marks all but not first duplicate as TRUE

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! In this case, the table looks like something you illustrated above. Please help me understand the following parts: (C2-1/24/3<$C$2:$C$13)*(C2+1/24/3>$C$2:$C$13))>1, and (C2-1/24/3<$C$1:C1))>0.

Comment: > 1 or> 0 compares the entire result of the SUMPRODUCT function. In turn, (C2-1/24/3<$C$2:$C$13)*(C2+1/24/3>$C$2:$C$13) checks whether the other record's time does not fall within the 20 minute interval. That is, I subtract 20 minutes (1/24/3) from C2 and look for any entry above that time. If yes, the expression returns 1, if not - 0. The same logic is applied with adding 20-minutes. If any of the expressions returns 0, then the result of multiplication is 0, if both returns 1, then the product is 1, which means that another time is found within 20 minutes.

Comment: In the case of sorted records, I only checked the last 20 minutes

Comment: This is brilliant! It took me a while to digest the formula, but once I figured, it was nice! Thank you for saving my time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following algorithm

IF (the time-step difference is <20; IF (if true 1) the pattern = pattern; (if true 2) “duplicate”; (if false 2) “no duplicate”; (if false 1) “no duplicate”)

Comment: I don't think the IF function could work. If you look at the table above, the time difference of A, could be in different rows, thus, it will be hard to use IF. I tried, and I didn't know what to do with it